# typedef void (AFX_MSG_CALL ClassName::*AFX_PMSGptr)(void);

Tags: c++, mfc

What is `AFX_MSG_CALL` in this line?

And also which word is typedef'ed??

```
typedef void (AFX_MSG_CALL ClassName::*AFX_PMSGptr)(void);
```

Comment: Search for it, either a file search in the IDE or on e.g. [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=AFX_MSG_CALL&emptyWatermark=true&searchButtonTooltip=Search%20MSDN&ac=4).

Comment: By the way, if you haven't done so yet, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Answer (score 0):

As for the `typedef`, it's for a member-function pointer named `AFX_PMSGptr` which will point to a member function in `ClassName` which takes no arguments and returns nothing.